# Opinion: Permissions: Write but not read for security purposes?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, backup, security

I have a number of connected systems, and am looking at setting up a separate server for incremental and full backups.

In order to also prevent loss of all systems/backups in the event of one becoming compromised, I am considering making this a drop-box sort of affair, with a write-only share mounted on each system that backups are pushed to.

I intend that, in the event something is attacked, the backup can be exposed to or pushed to the affected system via a newly created read-only share, and then restored from there - but the system itself can't be accessed.

One of our competitors recently lost their entire business because even their backups were connected - so they had nothing to restore from.

I will also download complete backups at suitable intervals.

Please poke holes in my plan.

Thanks.

Comment: "One of our competitors recently lost their entire business because even their backups were connected - so they had nothing to restore from." read only does not protect you if someone can write to it from somewhere. You are 1 `> {backupfile}` away from getting it erased. I would prevent WRITE on files **present** on the disk. Use time based directories and mark them with the immutable bit: I say why let -anyone but root- access those files.

Comment: Personally I'd leave the share as read/write, but set up some machinery to create snapshots of these, either at regular intervals or after the client signals that it has pushed all its data to it. Means use of some copy-on-write file system on the backup server. Personally I'd go with BSD, zfs and ECC-enabled hardware, since I already lost backups (but luckily not the corresponding life data) to btrfs corruption once, possibly due to bad memory. I'd also use rsync instead of the share, since I guess it might be more efficient. Plus `--fake-super` means cleaner permissions to the backups.

Answer (score 19):

> Please poke holes in my plan.

Sure. Only removing read does not prevent you from problems. Any attempt to modify requires write permissions. An attacker can then still write the file empty (he only needs to know where the file is).

Why not lock down anything on that disk regarding backups except for appending new data?

Possible setup:

```
/backups/20160911/backup.tar.gz
/backups/20160912/backup.tar.gz
/backups/20160913/backup.tar.gz
```

Create a script that does

```
chattr -R +a /backups/
chattr -R +i /backups/*.tar.gz
```

`+i` means "immutable"; nothing can be done to these files or directories. Not even root can alter it (that includes removing, editing, writing, adding new files. Anything). Even root needs to remove this (with `-i`) before root can do something to these files.

`+a` means "append"; Same rules as `-i` with 1 exception. Nobody is allowed to any alterations to the file or directory *except adding to it*. And again: even root needs to remove this (with a `-a`) before the file or directory can be changed where the change is not appending stuff to it.

(above might need some tweaking. 1 big backup file might be ehm not the best approach. Something with sub directories and file might be better. So that would need an adjustment to these 2 lines: for instance ONLY do this on old directories and do "today" manually when the backup is done. Then this becomes

```
chattr -R +i /backups/{not_today}
chattr -R +a /backups/{today}
```

Have this script run at intervals so if at any time someone changes something inside `/backups/` this resets the permissions for all backups.

Directories and files can be added to "today" and after your backup is done you could add the +i manually. Create a good admin password and nobody but the admin is going to touch these files. Ever.

By the way: also consider storing backups on-line. We have our backups in a multiple of google instances (we have 3 live systems on 3 continents that share the data each making a fallback instance on another continent and those each share a backup system).

Comment: I'm not a pro on Linux, but couldn't root open /dev/hda1 for example and modify the file even if there is the immutable flag?

Comment: @Advancid The answer already mentions that they can remove the immutable bit if they're that determined. The protection here doesn't claim to provide security against an attacker with root access.

Comment: @Advancid yes, root can do anything. That is also the ONLY way to remove this: root needs to do this.

Comment: @Advancid As far as I can tell the use case is for if the backup server is not itself compromised, to prevent other servers (which are compromised) from using their normal access to the backup server to destroy the backups.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `read` permission from the files or directories you want unreadible.

The permissions are:

```
u - Owner
g - group
o - others
```

Turn off read for everyone and right for everyone you want to have write access.

```
$ chmod -R ugo-r [path]
```

The directory [path] and all it's files and subdirectories will have this attribute.  In this case the `-r` (no read access).

Comment: It would be simpler to remove the x bit from the parent directory

Comment: @Zanna I thought of that, however that would defeat the OP's criterion for writing to the sub-directories.

Comment: oh yeah you're right :) It would also be simpler (and I think I'm not being foolish this time) to do `a-r`

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is as safe as disconnected backups. Download your backups onto an external drive and unplug it from the network after copying the backup onto it. Get a number of drives and rotate them.

For example, buy 5 1Tb drives (total cost < $300). Assign 3 of them as daily backups; each day connect one and copy the backup onto it, then diconnect. Assign one as a weekly backup and one as monthly and do the same.

Keep some of the drives in a second location in case of fire or theft.

This approach secures you against many different data loss threats.

If your system is all server based, use a cloud equivalent. Set up some servers on different providers (amazon, google, azure). Daily connect to another server and sftp your backup onto that server then disconnect. Keep multiple copies so you're not backing up over a good copy.

But nothing is as un-hackable as a physical copy you disconnect from any network and keep in an offsite location.